# PHP class return multiple arrays independently from various functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, return

I am starting to work with PHP classes and have the following need:

I want to create a Class where I have 2 functions returning 1 array each. The 2 arrays can be used either withing the class (by other functions) or outside the class. How would I return the 3 arrays?

What I tried is to have other functions that just return the array value, so I can use it outside. Is this the most efficient way? Is there a better and quicker way to return my arrays independently?

So far I have something like this:

```
class playersData
{
    private $players = array();
    private $resultados = array();
    public function myPlayers ()
    {
        return $this->players();
    }

    public function playersQuery
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM scoreboard";
        $playersQuery = $con->prepare($query);
        $playersQuery->execute();
        $this->players = $playersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);         
    }
    function checkPartidos 
      {
        $queryResultados = "SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE ganador <> 0";
        $result = $con->prepare($queryResultados);
        $result->execute();
        $this->$resultados = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to return 3 individual arrays or are you trying to create a multiple array, with 3 arrays in one array like so:
array[0][1] | array[0][2] | array[0][3]?

Comment: Ideally 3 individual arrays which I could access easily either within the Class or outside

Comment: What about instead of returning three arrays, it returns an object that holds three arrays?  Or, accepts three aliases that can have an array assigned to them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return 3 values at the same time.
In case of variables you can use:-

```
return $a.'|'.$b.'|'.$c;
```

then
**explode the string by |.**

In case of arrays you can use:-

```
function testFunction() {
  $newArray = array();
  $newArray[] = array('a1', 'a2');
  $newArray[] = array('b1', 'b2');

  return $newArray;
}
```

Create dynamic array of you arrays and return the one. Please try.

Comment: As pe my understanding there is no other way to return multiple values at the same time.